# Express.js, Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I have simple express server which looks like that:

**Epxress application:**

```
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

app.use('/bundle', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/bundle')));

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(compression());

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', "max-age=60, must-revalidate, private");
    res.sendFile( path.join(__dirname, 'index.html') );
});


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://%s:%s`, host, port);
});
```

And simple **html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Router test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside of bundle.js i have ReactJS application with client-side routing:

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="about2" component={About2} />
            <Route path="about3" component={About3} />
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Whenever i try to navigate to **domain:port/** (this route is supported by router) everething is OK.
But when i try to navigate to more complex URL, like **domain:port///..** etc i got an error in browser:

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

looke like instead of send bundle.js from static server response with index.html and inside bundle.js there is html markup.

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: try  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>

Comment: @Utro works for me. thanks!

Comment: @KokovinVladislav thanks, it works in my case

Answer (score 13):

There seems to be a loopback occuring, since the `*` rule is serving a `index.html` every time, and when `bundle.js` is not found, it will serve `index.html` instead, thus trying to parse `<` as javascript.

A sort of *index-ception* if you will...

Answer (score 4):

> **Step 1**

Folder structure:

```
public

   -> index.html

   -> bundle.js
```

> **Step 2**

Configure static path like this

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

> **Step 3**

Ensure if it is properly configured .Go to browser and access your js file directly like

```
localhost:3000/bundle.js
```

If you see your javascript ...Hurrray. If not then fight with step 2 then check step 3

> **Step 4**

use same path in script tag in ui like

```
<script src="/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by adding the following line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put simply** remove the DOT from   in index.html and the sub routes will work! As express will always find the bundle with a * catch all route

My fix is in. my repo, check it out: https://github.com/nickjohngray/staticbackeditor

**To Understand why and how to do this read on:**

The fix is to  tell webpack when it outputs the script tag to tell it to make the path to the bundle absolute (not relative ) to do this in webpack.config set the  publicPath '/' ( root) and filename 'bundle.js' , then the HtmlWepackPlugin will embed the script tag like

```
<script src="/bundle.js">
```

and that's what we want!

**NOT** the

```
<script src="./bundle.js">
```

Here is a snippet of my webpack.config to allow sub routes

```
 entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.tsx'],
    output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
       filename: 'staticbackeditor.js',
       publicPath: '/'
    }
```

Here an example of the flow if the path is relative: like

```
<script src="./bundle.js">
```

that's wrong! Kill the "**.**"

**Environment**

Backend is express server  and the bundle.js and index.html files are in the public static dist folder

Express has a catch all route for all requests using * that serves the index.html file like

```
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist', 'index.html'))
})
```

Index.html file has this script tag ( notice the . that makes this path relative )

```
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

Steps

- User requests  pages/edit route
- Express gives back index.html file
- Web browser reads this file
- Browser finds the script tag
- Browser makes request to get the script with the path ./bundle.js
- Express looks for this file in the static folder
- It does not find it ,
- so it returns index.html again as the catch all route is triggered
- And BANG web browser gives error.

So the server returned index.html instead of bundle.js
This occurred because the catch all route was run sine express did not find  bundle.js
In the folder edit.

**Right Flow**
Now! If we  change the html file script’s source to an absolute path so express will find it no matter what path the user is on

- User requests  pages/edit route
- Express gives back index.html file
- Web browser reads this file
- Browser finds the script tag
- Browser makes request to get the script with the path /bundle.js
- ( notice above the . is gone! )
- Express looks for this file in the static folder
- It finds it ,
- so it returns bundle.js
  And BANG! The sub routes work!

Comment: the github link is broken :(