# Express Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My **webpack-dev-server** works just fine but I wanted to achieve something similar with **express.js**. However, I'm getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.

Below is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const open = require('open');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../app/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

And below is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Yes boy</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="transformed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import React from 'react';
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const routes = require('./routes');
const GlobalCSS = require('./styles/main.scss');

/* eslint-disable no-unused-var */

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

routes.js

```
const routes = ( // eslint-disable-line no-extra-parens
  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={hashLinkScroll}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="nav" component={Nav} />
    <Route path="hero" component={Hero} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="footer" component={Footer} />
    <Route path="building" component={Building} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
project
  app/
    components/
      App.js
    index.html
    index.js
    routes.js
  build/
    index.html
    transformed.js
  tools/
    server.js
  webpack.config.js
```

Let me know if you guys have any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: You should include the code for your index.js file which I assume is built into transformed.js?

Comment: i think the issue is in this line: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../app/index.html'));` u r joining the current `dirname` with path of `index.html` file, n file does not exist at that place, u directly use this: `res.sendFile( '../app/index.html');`

Comment: updated my question @AndrewFont

Comment: @MayankShukla I myself think the root problem must be on that line. I may be wrong though. I've tried your suggestion but I am not getting a `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile` **Internal Server Error**

Comment: try this one, put ur `server.js` file outside of the `tool` folder, i mean like this: `project/server.js` and then use this line `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './app/index.html'));` if the problem is because of that it will get resolved by this :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Still no luck, I've even tried with removing the `path.join` again. I'm not getting the **Internal Server Error** anymore but in both cases I end up with the `Unexpected token <` issue.

Comment: one more thing, u gave the reference of  `transformed.js` in `html` file like this `src="transformed.js"`, and this file exist inside `build` folder, how ur html load this js ??

Comment: @MayankShukla there's an `index.html` in build as well.

Comment: but u r returning `index.html` file of `app` folder. so it will search for `js` in `app`, i think.

Comment: any luck or still facing issue ?

Comment: @MayankShukla still stuck. I've refered to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743275/express-js-unexpected-token) and I think I'm facing the problem BlockChange mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's all working now. The problem was with my assets which were not served from the memory. The solution was using `webpack-dev-middleware` in my case.

This is what I've added to my `server.js`:

`app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));`

**compiler** is your webpack export:

`const webpack = require('webpack');
 const config = require('../webpack.config');
 const compiler = webpack(config);`

**publicPath** should point to your `output` in your `webpack.config` which gets you your assets:

`output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'transformed.js'
  },`