# React app throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when running on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine, deployment, create-react-app

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@codemirror/lang-python": "^0.19.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@uiw/react-codemirror": "^4.1.0",
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.63.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pushstate-server": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.18.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start-dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`app.yaml`:

```yaml
env: standard
runtime: nodejs14
```

My `server.js` file through which I run the app:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

It starts the express server on the 8080 port and serves the `build` directory. When I run it on localhost, it works perfectly. But when I deploy it on Google App Engine with this command `gcloud app deploy`, it opens the app and writes this in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 2.cf168530.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.3ec04766.chunk.js:1
```

[Screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNoqy.png). Also, this is a URL to my [app](https://pm-user-agent-cc.el.r.appspot.com/?token=cddcabc8bb87074c506d957f3d0d8014149359f2a7c79eff89d30dcf146313c3) if it'd be useful (please, don't remove the `id` query, otherwise it'll redirect you to the previous page from where you opened the app).

Comment: Is your issue related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743275/express-js-unexpected-token#39352127

Comment: @Cadet no, I've read a lot of similar questions, but none of them solved the issue. However, it's solved now because I added URL patterns in my app.yaml files, but I still don't get why it doesn't work without the patterns

Comment: @ArseniyKoshelnik Can you please elaborate on the changes you mentioned above? I'm facing similar issue with no solution

Answer (score 0):

Replying to this since I just ran into the issue myself and couldn't find an exact answer.

This is happening because the `app.get('/*')` route is catching any requests that don't match any previously declared routes or static paths. So instead of the app serving the correct js/css/image etc, it serves the `index.html` file. Hence the unexpected '<' token.

This can mean (at least) two things:

1. **You have not declared a static route for the file in question.** Which
   does not appear to be the case in the question above.
2. **The static route may exist, but the file does not.** In which case express will move on to the catch-all route and serve up index.html. As mentioned by the question asker, using URL pattern handlers for static directories in the app.yaml will indeed prevent express from doing this, if you want to avoid it entirely.

In my case, my browser had cached an out of date `index.html` file with references to `css/js` build files that no longer existed, and a hard refresh fixed it.